# common object/function between different controllers in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, controller

I'm new in C# Web API and I am confused for the .cs file and folder structure that I am not sure where I should put the common object & function.

For example, now I created a simple class Obj, a function, and two controllers:

```
// Obj.cs under Models folder
public class Obj
{
     public int X;
     public int Y;
     public Obj()
     { x = 0; y = 0;}
}

public int GetRandom()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    return r.Next();
}

public class XController : ApiController
{
     public void Add()
     {
         obj1.X += GetRandom();  
     }
}

public class YController : ApiController
{
     public void Add()
     {
         obj1.Y += GetRandom();  
     }
}
```

The question is where should I put create the obj1 and the function so two Controllers also able to access them.
Currently, I just create an extra .cs file under the whole project and set them to be static.

```
// TestingExample.cs under project
public static class TestingExample
{
    public Obj obj1;
    public void Init()
    {
        obj1 = new Obj();
    }
    public int GetRandom()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        return r.Next();
    }
}

// XController.cs under Controllers folder
public class XController : ApiController
{
     public void Add()
     {
         TestingExample.obj1.X += TestingExample.GetRandom();  
     }
}

// YController.cs under Controllers folder
public class YController : ApiController
{
     public void Add()
     {
         TestingExample.obj1.Y += TestingExample.GetRandom();  
     }
}
```

The structure will like:

```
Project
---Models
-----Obj.cs
---Controllers
------XController.cs
------YController.cs
---TestingExample.cs
```

But I think that seems is quite stupid to do it and make the project structure become very bad.
Can anyone suggest me any good practice for this case? Thanks!

Comment: The question is why you need to access the same object in two different controllers.

Comment: because different controller responsible to control different things..

Comment: Well in that case it is more useful to have this object in some persistent storage and retrieve, modify and store it back wherever and whenever you need

Comment: so that's why I thought to create a static class and put the object in it so any other class can access that object, but I think there is a much better solution